Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D' even though image source is correct
I am trying to create an animation on scroll using an image sequence, but keep running into this error:
"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.
at render"
This implies that the image path is incorrect, but I'm almost certain it's correct. "console.log(images[frameIndex]);" is returning an image element with the correct path. Is there any other reason I would be getting this error?
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';


function getCurrentFrame(index) {
  return `${index.toString().padStart(4, "0")}.jpg`;
}

const ImageCanvas = ({ scrollHeight, numFrames, width, height }) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [frameIndex, setFrameIndex] = useState(0);

  // Step 1: Load images
  function preloadImages() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= numFrames; i++) {
      const img = new Image();
      const imgSrc = getCurrentFrame(i);
      console.log(imgSrc);
      img.src = imgSrc;
      setImages((prevImages) => [...prevImages, img]);
    }
  }

  // Step 2: Handle scroll events
  const handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollFraction = window.scrollY / (scrollHeight - window.innerHeight);
    const index = Math.min(
      numFrames - 1,
      Math.ceil(scrollFraction * numFrames)
    );

    if (index <= 0 || index > numFrames) {
      return;
    }

    setFrameIndex(index);
  };

  // Step 3: Set up canvas
  const renderCanvas = () => {
    const context = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
    context.canvas.width = width;
    context.canvas.height = height;
  };

  // Step 4: Render images to canvas
  useEffect(() => {
    preloadImages();
    renderCanvas();
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!canvasRef.current || images.length < 1) {
      return;
    }

    const context = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
    let requestId;

    const render = () => {
      console.log(images[frameIndex]);
      context.drawImage(images[frameIndex], 0, 0);
      requestId = requestAnimationFrame(render);
    };

    render();

    return () => cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
  }, [frameIndex, images]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: scrollHeight }}>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
    </div>
  );
};


export default ImageCanvas;


Although I wasn't able to fully get this function to work, I did figure out the error and want to put this here in case anyone else runs into this issue. By moving the image sequence folder to the public folder and updating the image source, I no longer get the above error.
function getCurrentFrame(index) {
  return `/desk/${index.toString().padStart(4, "0")}.jpg`;
}

